# KnockoutJS with PagerJS stop working after data bound

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, pagerjs

I'm working on KnockoutJS with PagerJS plugin and found this problem. I don't know if it is related to PagerJS or not but here's the problem.

I use `page` binding of pager.js with `sourceOnShow` property and there are child page inside the source contents bound with an observable property of its parent's ViewModel.

When the observable property changes, the child tried to update new data. But after the first value is bound, it seems it was stopped working. I put some logs in between each steps and the result comes as follows:

The result of my sample code displays only the `job_id`, the rest displays blocks with empty bindings and the console logged only `log1` and `log2`. No other errors logged. As if it stopped working after the first binding.

my code is, for example

the `main page`

```html
<script src="/js/jobspage.js"></script>
<!-- some elements -->
<div data-bind="page: {
    id: 'somepage',
    title: 'Some Page',
    sourceOnShow: 'template/somepage',
    role: 'start'
}"></div>
<div data-bind="page: {
    id: 'jobs',
    title: 'Jobs',
    sourceOnShow: 'template/jobs',
    with: JobsPageVM
}"></div>
<div data-bind="page: {
    id: 'other',
    title: 'Other Page',
    sourceOnShow: 'template/otherpage'
}"></div>
```

the `/template/jobs`

```html
<div class="jobs" id="main" role="main">
    <div class="job-list" data-bind="page: {role: 'start'}">
        <!-- ko foreach: jobitems -->
        <div data-bind="event: {click: item_clicked}">
            <!-- item description -->
            <!-- item_clicked will set the selectedItem (observable) property of JobsPageVM -->
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <div class="job-info" data-bind="page: {id: 'jobinfo', with: selectedItem}">
        <!--ko text: console.log('log1')--><!--/ko-->
        <!-- some elements -->
        <!--ko text: console.log('log2')--><!--/ko-->
        Job ID : <span class="job-value" data-bind="text: job_id"></span>
        <!--ko text: console.log('log3')--><!--/ko-->
        Job Title : <span class="job-value" data-bind="text: job_title"></span>
        <!--ko text: console.log('log4')--><!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

the `jobspage.js`

```javascript
var JobsPageVM = function () {
    var self = this;
    var dataitems = ko.observableArray();

    self.isLoading = ko.observable(true);
    self.searchTerm = ko.observable("");
    self.jobitems = ko.computed(function () {
        var search_input = self.searchTerm().toLowerCase();
        if (search_input === "") {
            return dataitems();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(dataitems(), function (item) {
                var data = item.cust_first_name + item.cust_last_name;
                return data.search(new RegExp(search_input, "i")) >= 0;
            });
        }
    }, this);

    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    self.branchID = ko.observable(sample_branch_id);

    self.getJobList = function (status) {
        self.isLoading(true);
        if (typeof (status) === "undefined") {
            status = "all";
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/job/branch/" + self.branchID(),
            data: {
                jobstatus: status
            },
            success: function (data) {
                dataitems(data); // data is an array of object items contains `job_id`, `job_title`, and more
                self.isLoading(false);
            },
            error: function (x, s, e) {
                console.log(x, s, e);
                self.isLoading(false);
            }
        });
    };

    self.item_clicked = function (vm, e) {
        self.selectedItem(vm);
        pager.navigate('jobs/jobinfo');
    };

    self.getJobList();
};
```

*I don't know whether it against the rule or not. This question was asked before but didn't answered, so I deleted and re-asking here. Thanks to @Stijn and @KristianNissen for help refine my question.

Comment: It's a lot easier to debug something like this on a working example. Could you provide a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: As a general hint, in Knockout "it works only once" often means that you accidentally overwrote (replaced) an observable instead of updating its value. That is, you create an observable `value = ko.observable('firstvalue')`, bind to that observable in your HTML, and later do something like `value = ko.observable('newvalue')` again instead of `value('newvalue')`.

Comment: Thanks @janfoeh I'm trying to make one. And I've checked there are no replacing values in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a kind of workaround, or maybe the solution. But I didn't quite sure the cause of the problem.

Originally, I tried to bind the `selectedItem` to the `page: {with: ...}` binding which resulted the problem above. Now I changed the binding of `selectedItem` with the element itself instead of inside `page:` binding.

I changed from this :

```
<div class="job-info" data-bind="page: {id: 'jobinfo', with: selectedItem}">
```

To this :

```
<div class="job-info" data-bind="page: {id: 'jobinfo'}, with: selectedItem">
```

And it seems to work fine now.